# Distribute contacts to business units

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit

We have Marketing Cloud Connect in place and it is available to all Business units (parent and children). Is there a way to Sync only filtered contacts to each child business units based on Service Cloud contact field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the use of Automation Studio (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_automation_studio.htm&type=5), you can automate [SQL queries](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm) that will populate only the contacts that you need into Data Extensions. 
You can either run an automation from Parent BU and populate Shared Data Extensions with filtered contacts for use in each Business Unit, or you could automate it in each Business Unit separately.

If you are not familiar with SQL, you can also automate drag and drop filters to refresh the data in Data Extensions on a schedule: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_use_a_filter_activity.htm&type=5. Again, you can automate it globally from Parent BU and populate Shared Data Extensions with filtered contacts for use in each Business Unit, or you could automate it in each Business Unit separately.